# Oracle INSTR replacement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, oracle, instr

Requirements: Before, I used instr() in Oracle to achieve the requirements, but now I want to use MySQL to achieve the same effect, and try to use the functions in MySQL to achieve it.

```
INSTR(A.SOME_THING.B,".",1,2)<>0 --ORACLE
```

Comment: Please clarify the exact issue you have. As long as there's no the same function in MySQL, you need to understand the purpose of this code and write another one using functions available in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, that's not that difficult for simple cases. But, as number of parameters raises, MySQL "replacement" for the same Oracle functionality gets worse.

As your code:

```
instr(some_thing, '.', 1, 2)
```

means

- search through `some_thing`
- for a dot
- starting from the first position
- and find dot's second occurrence

you can't do that in a simple manner using MySQL, as you'll need a user-defined function. Something like this (source is [INSTR Function - Oracle to MySQL Migration](https://www.sqlines.com/oracle-to-mysql/instr); I suggest you have a look at the whole document. I'm posting code here because links might get broken):

```
 DELIMITER //
 
  CREATE FUNCTION INSTR4 (p_str VARCHAR(8000), p_substr VARCHAR(255), 
     p_start INT, p_occurrence INT)
  RETURNS INT
  DETERMINISTIC
  BEGIN
    DECLARE v_found INT DEFAULT p_occurrence;
    DECLARE v_pos INT DEFAULT p_start;
 
    lbl:
    WHILE 1=1 
     DO
    -- Find the next occurrence
    SET v_pos = LOCATE(p_substr, p_str, v_pos);
 
    -- Nothing found
    IF v_pos IS NULL OR v_pos = 0 THEN
      RETURN v_pos;
    END IF;
 
    -- The required occurrence found
    IF v_found = 1 THEN
      LEAVE lbl;
    END IF;
 
    -- Prepare to find another one occurrence
    SET v_found = v_found - 1;
    SET v_pos = v_pos + 1;
    END WHILE;
 
    RETURN v_pos;
  END;
  //
 
  DELIMITER ;
```

Use it as

```
SELECT INSTR4('abcbcb', 'b', 3, 2);
```

and get **6** as a result.

Answer (score 0):

In OracleDB the code

```
INSTR(column, ".", 1, 2) <> 0 --ORACLE
```

checks does the column contains at least 2 point chars in the value.

In MySQL this can be replaced with, for example,

```
LENGTH(column) - LENGTH(REPLACE(column, '.', '')) >= 2
```